# VS2008: Launching the executable for a project that isn't the active project in a solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In VS2008, Is it possible to launch the executable for a project that is not the active project in the solution? (i.e. its name is not in bold).

Not debugging it - just launching it. As far as I can see, you just have to drop in to Windows Explorer and double click the .exe! Am I missing a menu item or shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click your solution and choose **Properties**.
2. Select **Common Properties** > **Startup Project**.
3. Select **Multiple startup projects**.
4. Next to the one you want to run, where it says None, change it to **Start without debugging**.

Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can right-click a project to debug it.  Right-click project -> Debug -> Start New Instance.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure of a way to do this outside of debug mode.  That is essentially what the facility of the 'Active Project' is for.  I typically set the active project and then use Shift+F5 to launch the application.

Comment: I said regular launching of the executable, not debugging.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure of a way.  That is what the facility of the 'Active Project' is for.  I've always set the Active Project and then used Shift+F5 to execute without debug mode.